# Why are there both Worksheet and Sheet objects?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, there is both a worksheet object and a Sheets object. Both do the same job, so why two objects for the same job??

Comment: No one can answer this except someone who wasn't actually working on this for Microsoft.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/frice/archive/2007/12/05/excel-s-worksheets-and-sheets-collection-what-s-the-difference.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sheets` accesses all types of sheet, including worksheets, charts etcetera, while `Worksheets` contains only worksheets and not charts or anything else.

Also, when there is more than one way to access the same object, one is frequently a legacy method retained so as to not break existing code.  Imagine if you'd written code referencing `Sheets`, and MS changed that to `Worksheets` and removed `Sheets`.  All your existing code would need to be changed too, and until you made the change, anyone using your code would be out of luck when they upgraded to the later version of Excel.  By retaining legacy properties/methods/events (even if hidden from the autocomplete lists), MS avoids the ire of inconvenienced developers and users.

Comment: Highly appreciated Mr.Monty Wild

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple types of sheet.  A `worksheet` is a regular sheet with a matrix of cells.  But you can also have `chart` sheets.

The [Worksheets collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508%28v=office.11%29.aspx) contains only worksheets, while the [Sheets collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174306%28v=office.11%29.aspx) contains all types of sheets.